# Selenium firefox instances freeze

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, automated-tests

I have a process running to scrape some information in bulk. It uses selenium and starts one firefox instance per URL to be scraped.

Similar processes run on multiple instances (to split workload). On one such instance, now I see processes freezing. They keep running for hours and hours. I have put no conditional waits in my selenium scripts. Other instances are running fine (which are also scraping the same website).

- Selenium version - 3.0.2
- Geckodriver version - 0.13.0
- Firefox version - Mozilla Firefox 50.1.0

I tried going through the geckodriver logs but could not make sense of anything. Any ideas on how to debug this further?